# How to correctly setup a CNAME / A Record when pointing to an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, cname-record, a-record

I have a web app hosted in Azure, which gives me a "custom" domain that is `awesomeapp.cloudapp.net`, and in the settings I can see the IP address: `123.456.789`

We have a domain `www.awesomeapp.com` that is pointing to a landing page promoting the company and the service of the app, and I have configured an A record like this:

`app.awesomeapp.com` => `123.456.789`

which works fine.

Problem is, sometimes  we have to shut down the VM, and when turned on again the IP is different, so the A record is no longer working. Is it valid if I set a CNAME record like this?

`app.awesomeapp.com` => `awesomeapp.cloudapp.net`

that would solve the problem of different IPs every time I turn on/off the machine. Is that going to work? Is that what CNAME is used for? Is it a good practice (as matter of performance and security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a CNAME is pretty standard practice with Azure for this very reason, it will prevent the IP changing being an issue.

If for some reason you need to use an A record then you would want to use a [reserved IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/), which will stay constant even if you reboot or shut down the VM.

Answer (score 3):

**Against CNAMEs:**

There is a (tiny) performance penalty, as the downstream DNS caches need to perform 2 DNS lookups, one for the CNAME and one for the A-Record the CNAME points to.
Vague, bogus arguments about CNAMEs having less "authority" or compatibility issues.

**In favor of CNAMEs:**

They provide a clean abstraction between hardware (physical servers) and services.
They simplify DNS management -- when a server moves, you only need to change one record.
After trying a couple of different ways to do this, I now have a personal favorite style. It is:

One A Record for each physical server; with a fairly low TTL (perhaps 30 minutes); giving the server a human-friendly name.
One CNAME for each service; with a high TTL (perhaps 24 hours); pointing to the above server names.
As the sole exeption to the rules above, the domain root is an A-Record, pointing to the webserver / web load balancer. (The @ is required to be an A-record.)
I find that this setup works well. It keeps extra DNS lookups for the CNAMES down; and if a server crashes I can still change public DNS around fairly fast.

Here's a (improvised) example in BIND syntax:

```
;name     ttl   class rr     value 
server01  30m   IN    A      192.168.0.3
server02  30m   IN    A      192.168.0.4

webmail   24h   IN    CNAME  server01
extranet  24h   IN    CNAME  server02
ftp       24h   IN    CNAME  server02
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) So in short words, that scenario of a CNAME instead of A would work?